# Postgres/Spring Data: how to use "order" as property name?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I have a model with a property called `order`:

```
@NotNull
@Column(name = "ORDER")
@EqualsAndHashCode.Include
private Integer order;
```

How can I make sure that order works when saving to my postgresql database?
I save it like this: `someRepository.save(itemWithOrder);`

The error I get is the following:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "order"

I do understand that `order` is a reserved word - I couldn't find a workaround though.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://vladmihalcea.com/escape-sql-reserved-keywords-jpa-hibernate/ . Anyway, if code is under your control you can have `@Column(name = "ORDERID")` and still use `order` in your Java code.

Comment: It is bad practice using reserved words as a column name. Even if you manage getting it accepted as at best it just causes confusion (developer not Postgres). However you can do  by double quoting it ( "Order"). Just make sure you **always** use double quotes and case on every use.

Comment: Just because there is  a way to do it (using the dreaded quoted identifiers) doesn't mean it's a good idea to do it. I would strongly recommend to find a different name that doesn't require quoting

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to rename the column name then use double quotes

```java
@NotNull
@Column(name = "\"ORDER\"") // <---
@EqualsAndHashCode.Include
private Integer order;
```